# Caesar Cipher using char * ? c++

Tags: c++, encryption, caesar-cipher, char-pointer

So i am trying to use the Ceasar Cipher with `char *`'s, I've written a simple function out like this:

```
char * Encrypt(char * s, int k)
{
    char * c = s;

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
       c[i] += k;

    return c;
}
```

that seems to look like it should work but it doesn't. It throws an error when running program.

Here is an example of how i call this function:

```
int main()
{
    cout << Encrypt("hello", 2) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And before you say "why not just use `string`?", well the answer is I'm writing C++ on a certain SDK that causes compiler errors when using `string`. Ok but yeah, any form of help will greatly be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you are not (or cannot) use `std::string`, then you should use the correct C library functions to *copy* the contents of `Source` into an appropriately sized array. Otherwise you are modifying `Source`.

Comment: Keep in mind that char is unsigned short, your encryption may not work if your key exceeds the value beyond char's range.

Comment: Let me guess, you call this function using a string literal? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. especially how you call this function.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Ehr what? A `char` is a `char`, `unsigned short` is a completely different type. The only commonality between `char` and `unsigned short` is that both are integer types.

Comment: A good starting point is to study a "C" language reference and/or an online course. You need to understand memory allocation. We all had to do that.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov: What do you mean "char is unsigned short"? Those are two different types, almost certainly with different ranges.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ok, i have added an example of how i call.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Can you please share your crystal ball with me?

Comment: @JeffCoderr You need to turn up your warnings in your compiler.  `Encrypt("hello", 2)` should generate a compiler warning/error.

Comment: What SDK complains about `std::string`? And what exactly does "throws an error" mean? Please update your question to show us the actual error message.

Comment: Your function is flawed.  You need use modulo 26.  For example, what letter is 'x` + 5?

Comment: @NathanOliver It's a very typical thing to happen when passing string literals to a function and try to modify it. I've seen it countless of times before. :)

Comment: *well the answer is I'm writing C++ on a certain SDK that causes compiler errors when using string** -- More than likely, [PEBCAK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PEBCAK)

Comment: They may be different types for the compiler, but in the way they're being used here suggest they're treated as numbers - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc953fe1.aspx

Comment: @DanielProtopopov A `char` is always a `char`.  It can be signed or unsigned but that is the only difference.  In every implementation it the `sizeof(char)` has to equal 1.  It is a integer type but it is never a `short` although it could take up the same space as a `short` if the system did 16 bit bytes.

Comment: @NathanOliver to be pedantic; `char`, `signed char` & `unsigned char` are all different types, so not just two (signed/unsigned) but three distinct types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String literals like `"Hello"` are *read only*. If you try to modify such a string you will have *undefined behavior*.

In C++ string literals are actually arrays of *constant* characters.

Using `char*` to access a string literal should have your compiler to scream a warning at you. If not you need to turn up your warning level or enable more warnings.

If you're really programming in C++ I suggest you learn about [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [find a good beginners book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read.

Comment: It is the modifying that is the problem. A good compiler/execution system will but the constant string in read-only memory.